# On clause conditions when joining tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to join the two tables “Table1” and “Table2”. For each Id in Table1, I have to get the StartTime and StopTime and refer to the Table2 whose DateTime is between the Table 1’s StartTime and StopTime and then retrieve the corresponding Point 1 and Point 2 from Table 2. I tried joining the two tables and in the on clause, I checked where Table1.StartTime >= Table2.DateTime and Table1.StopTime <= Table2.DateTime. But Google big query does not support >= in on clauses. Just wondering whether there is any supplement for this. Any help would be appreciated.

Table1:

```
Id    StartTime                 StopTime    

1    2016-10-05 12:44:21 UTC    2016-10-05 12:59:31 UTC
```

Table2:

```
Id  DateTime                   Point1       Point2

1   2016-10-05 12:44:21 UTC     52.9        53.2
2   2016-10-05 12:44:24 UTC     33.1        90.1
3   2016-10-05 12:50:47 UTC     52.3        90.8
4   2016-10-05 12:53:23 UTC     52.3        -111.11
```

Resultant table:

```
Id    StartTime                 StopTime                Point1      Point2

1    2016-10-05 12:44:21 UTC    2016-10-05 12:59:31 UTC   52.9      53.2
2    2016-10-05 12:44:21 UTC    2016-10-05 12:59:31 UTC   33.1      90.1
3    2016-10-05 12:44:21 UTC    2016-10-05 12:59:31 UTC   52.3      90.8
4    2016-10-05 12:44:21 UTC    2016-10-05 12:59:31 UTC   52.3     -111.11
```

Comment: Does Bigquery has the same limitation on where condition? If not,  you could write it as a Cross Join + where condition (likely with performance impact)

Comment: The limitation is in BigQuery legacy SQL. If you use standard SQL there are a lot more options that are valid in join conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For BigQuery Standard SQL (see [Enabling Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql))

```
SELECT Table1.Id, StartTime, StopTime, Point1, Point2
FROM Table1 join Table2
ON Table1.StartTime <= Table2.DateTime 
AND Table1.StopTime >= Table2.DateTime
```

or you can use below in ON clause

```
ON Table2.DateTime BETWEEN Table1.StartTime AND Table1.StopTime
```