# Join with <= in the On clause in Google bigquery

Tags: join, google-bigquery

I want to execute a query with `join` in Google `bigquery` that has '<=' instead of '=' in it's on clause:

```
select s.count_value as count_value,s.total as total,sum(p.total) as accumulated    from  stats s   join stats p on p.rn <=s.rn   group by count_value,total,s.rn
```

When I run this query, I receive an error message saying:

> Error: ON clause must be AND of = comparisons of one field name from each table, with all field names prefixed with table name.

Any idea how I can implement this query?

Comment: Make sure to [enable standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql) for the query. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39900869/on-clause-conditions-when-joining-tables.

Comment: I run it through bq command line tool. Do you know how I can enable standard SQL in command line tool?

Comment: bq query --use_legacy_sql=false ......

Comment: Yes! it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should enable Standard SQL to do such JOINs
See [Enabling Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql)

in CLI - just add the --use_legacy_sql=false flag to your command line statement.